# Animate Bitmap within ImageView (Emulate Newsstand app - Ken Burns Effect)

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-kenburnsview

How would one emulate the header image in Google's [Newsstand app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.magazines)?

The effect I would like to implement is a "moving" Image where the bitmap inside the ImageView is slowly panned and zoomed.

Thanks

Comment: do you have a specific example of what you want? Looking through the Newsstand app I can't see any sort of animations that fit your description. I can only imagine you're talking about a kind of [parallax effect](https://github.com/ideaismobile/AKParallax-Android) perhaps?

Comment: No it's not the parallax effect I'm referring to it's the moving images you see behind the tabbed navigation. Select a magazine such as New Scientist and you'll see the background images in the header slowly move/animate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled across [this repo](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar) on GitHub that seems like it could be what your looking for? It is a library that provides an implementation of the ActionBar used by the newsstands app, as described [in this blog post by Flavien Laurent](http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/11/20/making-your-action-bar-not-boring/)

Comment: what a nice library. do you know if the image on the top could also be changing its size instead of being scrolled to above the screen?

Comment: I would imagine so, if not you could probably fork the repo and swap out the animation for one more to your liking.

Comment: just to be clear, i'm talking about the large image, the background behind the action bar icon. do you think they have it?

Comment: That is called as the Ken Burns effect and more information is [Here](https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView) - Maybe helpful for someone who stumbles upon here.